# Is there a default media type for GET and other methods

Tags: ietf-restconf

Is there any default media type when the query is not specified with any supported media types in RESTCONF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no standard default. This is server implementation dependent, so do not rely on it.

From [draft-ietf-netconf-restconf-17, Section 5.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-netconf-restconf-17#section-5.2), Message Encoding:

> The server MUST support the "Accept" header field and "406 Not
> Acceptable" status-line, as defined in [RFC7231].  The response
> output content encoding formats that the client will accept are
> identified with the Accept header field in the request.  If it is not
> specified, the request input encoding format SHOULD be used, or the
> server MAY choose any supported content encoding format.

> If there was no request input, then the default output encoding is
> XML or JSON, depending on server preference.  File extensions encoded
> in the request are not used to identify format encoding.

And from [draft-ietf-netconf-restconf-17, Section 7.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-netconf-restconf-17#section-7.1), Error Response Message:

> The client SHOULD specify the desired encoding(s) for response
> messages by specifying the appropriate media-type(s) in the Accept
> header.  If the client did not specify an Accept header, then the
> same structured syntax name suffix used in the request message SHOULD
> be used, or the server MAY choose any supported message encoding
> format.  If there is no request message the server MUST select
> "application/yang-data+xml" or "application/yang-data+json",
> depending on server preference.

Answer (score 1):

The final RFC stood by the draft, just as @predi said:

On [Message Encoding, Section 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8040#section-5.2):

> If there was no request input, then the default output encoding is
> XML or JSON, depending on server preference.  File extensions encoded
> in the request are not used to identify format encoding.

And [Error Message Response, Section 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8040#section-7.1)

> If the client did not specify an "Accept" header, then the same
> structured syntax name suffix used in the request message SHOULD be
> used, or the server MAY choose any supported message-encoding
> format. If there is no request message, the server MUST select
> "application/yang-data+xml" or "application/yang-data+json",
> depending on server preference.